# Wordpress - Moving website admin section

Tags: wordpress

I have successfully moved a wordpress site from /test directory to the root, so now the website url looks like www.example.com. Fine. 
However the admin section (wp-admin) still points to /test directory and so the url looks like www.example.com/test/wp-admin/...
How can I make it like www.example.com/wp-admin/...?

Please notice that I'm not interested in a simple redirection (now the customer is able to access the admin section with www.example.com/wp-admin, but then he's redirected to www.example.com/test/wp-admin/..., and it's not what he wants.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The WordPress website has [clear instructions for moving a WordPress installation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: Note that this question is off topic here. It's more suited for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or the WordPress forums.

Comment: I've already followed the instructions on codex (in fact the website "front-end" points to the root instead of /test directory), but the admin section does not. Is it normal behaviour or something went wrong in your opinion?

For the off topic, I'm sorry but I was thinking that SO is a general purpose platform (I see questions about anything in SO), that's why I posted here.

Comment: No, SO is for programmin questions only. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok, got it, my fault. But can you at least answer my last question ("Is it normal behavior that changing site url doesn't affect admin section or something went wrong during migration?"). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Everything is documented in http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

You may need to change many URLs in post/page content; if so, see https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB as suggested in the above Docs.

There is no need to create a new Wordpress install.

Also see http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install if you want to keep core Wordpress files and folders in a subfolder, but have the site appear to be at root for the end user.

Answer (score -1):

You should not move wordpress this way. Here is what you do:

1. Install Clean Wordpress Installation on the new domain.
   *(www.original.com)*
2. Use a plugin* to make back-up on your test domain.
   *(www.original.com/test/)*
3. Install plugin* on the new domain, and restore back-up from test
   domain. *(www.orignal.com)*
4. Update your *style.css, header.php, index.php & footer.php* if it
   contains hard written links to your test domain.

You cannot simply move a wordpress installation - as most entries, links etc. are stored in the database. If you move folders in your ftp they will still point to the old database. This is why you have to duplicate your site, where the database entries will be automatically updated to your new site domain. Hard written links in any theme php files will have to be updated.

Although your problem depends on how your pointers/sites are set-up in c-panel. If you have to change pointers for your directory, you might have to back-up your website and upload it to a different domain so your new site can access the restoration back-up file via http request.

*Plugins such as *wp clone, duplicator*.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with moving a WordPress installation, the procedure is documented in detail.

Comment: You definitely cannot copy and paste a WordPress Installation to a different directory. Your WordPress site will stop working or have serious issues such as the above. This is the same with any other CMS or a website that works with a database. To my suprise I didn't expect an such a comment, as this obviously direct cause of the issue.

Comment: I take the time to share experience and provide helpful instructions in an organized matter, and my response get's down-voted by some 'elite' stack user who doesn't even have a proper website.. F* this community.

Comment: "Install Clean Wordpress Installation on the new domain." There is no reason to do this; it's very easy to move a subfolder install to root. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress